# Integration of an exponential function with an extra constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral as shown below.
$$ \int_{-a}^a e^{jkx(sin\theta cos\phi-\alpha) }dx$$

Normally I would define the $sin\theta co\phi$ as $x$ and solution of the integral would become
$$a\dfrac{sinX}{X}$$

What does $\alpha$ term change in the calculations?

Note that $j$ is the imaginary unit like $i$.

Comment: What is $j$? And what is $\sin\left(\theta\right)\text{co}\left(\phi\right)$? Don't you mean: $\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)$?

Comment: To what are you integrating? With respect to?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we have the following integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right):=\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha\exp\left(\text{n}x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}=\text{n}x$, so:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{1}{\text{n}}\int_{-\text{n}\alpha}^{\text{n}\alpha}\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{du}=\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\right]_{-\text{n}\alpha}^{\text{n}\alpha}=\frac{\exp\left(\text{n}\alpha\right)-\exp\left(-\text{n}\alpha\right)}{\text{n}}\tag2$$

Now, you can substitute:

$$\text{n}=\text{k}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\beta\right)i\tag3$$

So:

- $$\exp\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\beta\right)i\right)=$$
  $$\cos\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\beta\right)\right)+\sin\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\beta\right)\right)i\tag4$$
- $$\exp\left(-\alpha\text{k}\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)-\beta\right)i\right)=\exp\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\beta-\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)\right)i\right)=$$
  $$\cos\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\beta-\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)\right)\right)+\sin\left(\alpha\text{k}\left(\beta-\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)\right)\right)i\tag5$$

So:

$$\frac{\exp\left(\text{n}\alpha\right)-\exp\left(-\text{n}\alpha\right)}{\text{n}}=\frac{2 \sin (\alpha  \text{k} (\beta -\sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi )))}{\beta  \text{k}-\text{k} \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi )}\tag6$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b = k(\sin\theta \cos\phi-\alpha)$

So, $$\int_{-a}^ae^{jbx}dx = \int_{-a}^a(\cos (bx) +j\sin(bx))dx = \frac{\sin(ab)-\sin(-ab)}{b} = \frac{2\sin(ab)}{b}\\=\frac2{k(\sin\theta \cos\phi-\alpha)}\sin\left[ak(\sin\theta \cos\phi-\alpha)\right]$$